# Incorrect rep graph

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-graph

Right now, my rep graph on Puzzling looks like this:
[image: rep graph]

That spike is my 100-rep Trusted bonus, but it's not a spike.  It's a **slope**.  Shouldn't the graph depict the rep increase as a perfect vertical line?

Comment: If you want accurate graph, see in your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/5361489/scripthero?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The graph does not track rep with millisecond precision; it only adds a single point to the graph every day. Today you have 100 more rep than yesterday.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)